# .htaccess redirect after replace a word?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to use .htaccess file to replace a word in a URL; something like this:

Example URL:

```
 http://example.com/oldword/test-page.html
```

Redirect to:

```
 http://example.com/newword/test-page.html
```

How can I use mod_rewrite to redirect every URL containing  **/oldword/**  to the same URL after replacing that word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
RewriteRule ^oldword/(.*)   /newword/$1   [L]
```

Edit:  It might not work exactly depending on your RewriteBase settings, but it'll be close.

Second Edit:  If you need to have a 301 Moved Permanently header associated with the old URLs, you can do something like this as well:

```
RewriteRule ^oldword/(.*)   /newword/$1   [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

see here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^oldword(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/newword$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

ciao,

Chris

Comment: It’s better to leave the protocol, host and port part away like zombat did. Additionally your rule would also redirect `/oldword-and-some-more` to `/newword-and-some-more` and I don’t think that’s what chiaf wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can redirect independent on what surrounds the 'oldword', which you want to replace:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /

   # Replace 'oldword' with 'newword' and 301 redirect 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)oldword(.*)$ /$1newword$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```