# Redirecting url to same URL with different character

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok so I am trying to implement a 301 redirect on my site.. Here is the code I have so far

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/games/(.*)/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/apps/$1/$2
```

The problem is that the second parameter on the old site uses a underscore (ex brain_puzzle) and I am trying to redirect it to "brain-puzzle". So for example:

http://mysite.com/games/brain_puzzle/4-pics-1-word/

will redirect to

http://mysite.com/apps/brain-puzzle/4-pics-1-word/

Any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about that specific case, you could do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799818/641451):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/games/brain_puzzle/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/apps/brain-puzzle/$2
```

If it's more general (different strings than `brain_puzzle`), some variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7650659/641451) can help you.

Comment: Yes, unfortunalely there could be other values in that bucket.. some single world, some double word with the dash

Comment: @tytyguy have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6068347/641451)? I think that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(games)/([^_]+)_(.*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^games/([^/_]+)/([^/_]*)/?$ /apps/$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

**This code will recursively replace all underscores with hyphens before doing a 301 redirect.**